# How to fix "Requested runtime 'python-3.8.10' is not available for this stack (heroku-22)"?

Tags: python, heroku

I am trying to push my project on web using Heroku with the command "git push heroku master", but it shows me: `Using Python version specified in runtime.txt remote:  !     Requested runtime 'python-3.8.10' is not available for this stack (heroku-22)` 
. Because I coded this app on python version 3.8.10, it is not supported by heroku-22. Is there any possibility of fixing it or downgrading the version or not?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#supported-runtimes

Comment: The currently supported Python 3.8 is python-3.8.14 on Heroku-20 stack. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack Try `heroku stack:set heroku-20` and `echo python-3.8.14 >runtime.txt`